# Configuration problem:Spring NamespaceHandler for [http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

> Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc].

can anyone tell why this error is happening?
this is my configuration.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: did u solve this ? wich jar version to put ? I also encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

@Tijo

You need to check few things:

1. Whether the Spring version you are using is 3.0. You are referring to spring-beans-3.0.xsd, spring-context-3.0.xsd and spring-mvc-3.0.xsd in your configuration, so you need to use Spring 3.0.* JARs.
2. You may already have all the required JARs in the build path, most likely as "Referenced libraries" by adding external JARs to your build path. You also need to keep all the JARs in the webapp's WEB_INF/lib/ folder (put them in that folder directly, and not in a sub-folder of WEB-INF/lib/). Only then your web server knows about them. This is what Bozho means.
3. This is more subtle. Make sure you do not have multiple Spring JAR versions in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

These are the same steps one needs to check for other NameSpaceHandler errors too, like

```
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
```

or

```
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace
[http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Spring needs a `NamespaceHandler` on the (runtime) classpath that can handle the `mvc:` namespace. This is the `MvcNamespaceHandler`, and it is located in the `spring-webmvc-xx.jar`. Put that on your classpath.

Comment: ya..i had included that jar file in the project classpath, but still getting the same error.

Comment: in the project - yes, but in the runtime classpath?

Comment: It works! I added `<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>` to my pom.xml and this problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this?

[maven shade plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523997/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace-http-www-sp/8574629#8574629)
or this
[maven shade plugin 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937767/spring-3-0-unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace/11978331#11978331)

It solved my problem with finding the spring context xml's.a link

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error while development on Eclipse. Some time it happens that required JAR is there at the correct location, but still this error message doesn't disappear. Don't Panic. First check if any of the above answers are working for you. If its not working follow below steps if you are facing this while development on Eclipse/STS.

1. Clean your Local Server (Tomcat in my case).
2. Remove project resource from server and Republish it.
3. Clean Build your project again and see the result.

Issue resolved in my case.

Answer (score 0):

> due to lack of spring-webmvc dependency It will happen so add the
>   spring-webmvc dependency to pom.xml (or add the jars if not using
>   maven or any build

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```