# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch]

Tags: spring, spring-batch

#### Situation

I am using Spring Batch to build an Accumulative Snapshot for our Data Warehouse and I am having a configuration roadblock that I cannot figure out.

I have created a Simple Spring Batch Project with STS (SpringSource Tool Suite 2.8.1) using the **Spring Template Project**. These were my two xml configuration files created:

**launch-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:batch.properties" />

<context:component-scan base-package="edu.kdc.visioncards" />

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="${batch.schema.script}" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<batch:job-repository id="jobRepository" />

<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml" />
```

and **module-context.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<description>Example job to get you started. It provides a skeleton for a typical batch application.</description>

<batch:job id="job1">
    <batch:step id="step1"  >           
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" start-limit="100" >
            <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job> 

</beans>
```

#### Problem

I run the following command to compile and package the project: **mvn clean compile install**

then I do as follows:

1. **cd** to **target** folder
2. Run the job through CommandLineJobRunner: **java -jar batchprimer-1.0.jar META-INF/spring/module-context.xml job1**

and I get the following error:

```
C:\stsworkspace\BatchPrimer\target>java -jar batchprimer-1.0.jar META-INF/spring
/module-context.xml job1
2011-12-15 12:03:53,421 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlAp
plicationContext] - <Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXml
ApplicationContext@84abc9: startup date [Thu Dec 15 12:03:53 EST 2011]; root of
context hierarchy>
2011-12-15 12:03:53,468 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefin
itionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/
spring/module-context.xml]>
2011-12-15 12:03:53,796 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.Com
mandLineJobRunner] - <Job Terminated in error: Configuration problem: Unable to
locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframew
ork.org/schema/batch]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/spring/module-context.xml]
>
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Config
uration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespa
ce [http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/spring/module-context.xml]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.err
or(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderC
ontext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderC
ontext.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.er
ror(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.pa
rseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.pa
rseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentRe
ader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentRe
ader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registe
rBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadB
eanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReade
r.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loa
dBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loa
dBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationCon
text.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtain
FreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<i
nit>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.st
art(CommandLineJobRunner.java:282)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.ma
in(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
```

#### Additional Stuff

In the target folder that got populated with the mvn install command I have as follows:

1. A **classes** folder
2. a **lib** folder with all my maven dependencies
3. a **maven-archiver** folder
4. a **test-classes** folder
5. a **batchprimer-1.0.jar**

Inside the jar, in the **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF**. I have as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver

Created-By: Apache Maven

Built-By: dpardo

Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_20

Main-Class: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJ
 obRunner

Class-Path: lib/spring-jdbc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-beans-3.0.6.R
 ELEASE.jar lib/spring-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-asm-3.0.6.REL
 EASE.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/spring-tx-3.0.6.RELEASE.ja
 r lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar lib/spring-aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar lib/spring
 -context-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-expression-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar li
 b/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar lib/spring-batch-core-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar lib/spr
 ing-batch-infrastructure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar lib/xstream-1.3.jar lib/xp
 p3_min-1.1.4c.jar lib/jettison-1.1.jar lib/commons-io-1.4.jar lib/com
 mons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar lib/commons-pool-1.3.jar lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar l
 ib/aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar lib/aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar lib/log4j-1.2.14.j
 ar lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar lib/mysql-conn
 ector-java-5.1.3.jar
```

So I do not think that it is a classpath issue because in the console it seems like it's finding the jars.

#### What I have tried

Based on the error, I pasted the following URL

http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/

and the address of the namespaces for Spring Batch seems to be correct. I have not found anything useful neither out there. I read somewhere that "something" could be overriding the namespaces of the files but did not really understand why, what, and/or how to solve it.

This is just out the box and already not working without having done any modifications, add-ons or anything. Any ideas?

Thanks

### SOLUTION

In addition to the marked as correct solution below. I also had to change the launch-context.xml from component scanning to regular spring wiring like this below:

```
<!-- Commented this 
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:batch.properties" />  


<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="${batch.schema.script}" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
-->
<!-- Replace it with this below -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${batch.jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${batch.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${batch.jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="placeholderProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:batch.properties" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I think Java only locates `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (and not `META-INF/spring/MANIFEST.MF`) – perhaps Java is using another manifest file. Check [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html) how to customize your manifest file. I also found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2842800/267197), which is somehow relevant, but you use the latest Spring version and this combination is working for me.

Comment: The MANIFEST.MF has always been right under META-INF sorry I misled. I will update the post real quick

Comment: Generally I give up. If you have nothing special, upload your jar+libs to file share. I will try to run it under debugger with breakpoint at `DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver#getHandlerMappings()` method (BTW, try to increase log level to DEBUG and see what this class reports; should look like [this](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Could-not-find-resource-errors-on-AMQ-startup-td3796187.html)).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Run the job through CommandLineJobRunner: java -jar
>   batchprimer-1.0.jar META-INF/spring/module-context.xml job1

**even with a complete target folder you have to provide the classpath information for the java command**, to ease the configuration you can try it with an all-in-one executable jar e.g. with [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) or an executable shell script (.bat/.sh) with all needed libraries, e.g. with [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/)

maven-shade-plugin example configuration (creates additional jar):

```
<plugin>
    <!-- create an all-in-one executable jar with maven-shade-plugin
         bound to phase:package 
         special handling for spring.handlers/spring.schemas files
         to prevent overwriting (maven-shade-plugin joins them to
         one file) 

         usage:
         cd to <project>/target
         java -jar hello-world-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT-executable.jar spring/batch/job/hello-world-job.xml helloWorldJob
         -->                     
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <!-- configures the suffix name for the executable jar
                     here it will be '<project.artifact>-<project.version>-executable.jar'-->
                <shadedClassifierName>executable</shadedClassifierName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

example appassembler configuration (creates subfolder structure and .bat/.sh):

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
        <installArtifacts>false</installArtifacts>
        <target>${project.build.directory}/appassembler</target>
        <defaultJvmSettings>
            <initialMemorySize>512M</initialMemorySize>
            <maxMemorySize>1024M</maxMemorySize>
            <extraArguments>
                <extraArgument>-Dlog4j.configuration=../etc/log4j/log4j.properties</extraArgument>
            </extraArguments>
        </defaultJvmSettings>
        <configurationDirectory>etc</configurationDirectory>
        <daemons>
            <daemon>
                <id>applicationName</id>
                <mainClass>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</mainClass>
                <commandLineArguments>
                    <commandLineArgument>spring/job-runner.xml</commandLineArgument>
                    <commandLineArgument>helloWorldJob</commandLineArgument>
                    <commandLineArgument>input.file.pattern=file:.../**/*.txt</commandLineArgument>
                </commandLineArguments>
                <platforms>
                    <platform>booter-unix</platform>
                    <platform>booter-windows</platform>
                </platforms>
            </daemon>
        </daemons>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate-daemons</goal>
                <goal>create-repository</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I have added the two xmls above in my pom and I run the following command: `java -jar batchprimer-1.0.jar META-INF/spring/module-context.xml job1` and i get **Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from batchprimer-1.0.jar** Any ideas?

Comment: Oh ok, the batchprimer-1.0.jar does not have a Manifest in it. I do not know why this shade plugin generates two jars. I run the same command on the other jar that it generated  `java -jar batchprimer-1.0-executable.jar META-INF/spring/module-context.xml job1` and it threw a Spring error. I will troubleshoot that, weird though because its a simple project, I have not touched a thing

Comment: the shade plugin creates an additional jar, the executable one, ill change the description a bit, but this is also stated on the plugin page

Comment: +1 for workaround, but I don't merge all jars into one for my web application, and Spring can still parse batch namespace.

Comment: Thanks everybody that contributed to solving my issue. I resolved it by using the first option `maven-shade-plugin`my final command was `java-jar batchprimer-1.0-executable.jar launch-context.xml job1`. Maybe I even had the xml in the command line wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I was using spring batch version 3.X.X and other spring dependencies versions 4.X.X , and received the above error. After some trial and error I found that maintaining all the spring versions similar fixed my issue. Hence suggest you to either use spring batch version 3.X.X or make you spring dependecy version for spring-jdbc and spring-tx to 2.X.X

Regards, Rave

Answer (score 0):

You need the spring-batch.jar on your runtime classpath. It provides a namespace handler that is capable of handling that specific namespace.

Comment: I have **spring-batch-core-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar**, **spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar** among other spring-XXX-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar(s) and other dependencies. And I am still having that error.

Comment: I run the java -jar command within the target folder that got filled up with classes and a **lib** folder with all the jars in it. The manifest file has a class-path entry with values: lib/spring-batch-core-2.1.7 etc.. I am going to add that to my post

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the META-INF/spring.handlers file in spring-batch-core-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar isn't being seen. This file contains

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/batch=org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.CoreNamespaceHandler
```

It looks like either a classpath problem or like the spring.handlers file in the other JARs (spring-context, e.g.) is somehow taking precedence.

Comment: Thanks, how do I control the order?

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia: The precedence should not play any role: all resources are scanned and namespace handlers are registered.

Comment: @dma_k so do you know what can I do about it?

Comment: @Viriato: Check my reply in the header: first make sure that your root `MANIFEST.MF` is al-right.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was simply missing the spring transaction dependency - or perhaps pointing to an old one. Replacing that with 3.1 took the error away.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - was a missing dependency rather than a weird setup issue for me too. I forgot the spring-security-config.