# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd'

Tags: java

I have downloaded a program of spring and trying to run it on my STS Eclipse whose  Version: 3.6.4.RELEASEP and runs on Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2).

I am getting the following error:

```
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/
     beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) 
     the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>
```

here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.prophesee.datafetcher" />
```

i have added dependencies in maven having  3.1.1. version of spring framework. i want to know where am i wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spring+failed+to+read+schema ...

Comment: Did you included whole spring context file or part of it, I see no end tags </beans:beans>

Comment: This is how I solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078262/failed-to-read-schema-document-after-maven-package