# org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException in spring compiled Jar

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I have looked around and SO and I have not found a solution that has solved this issue for me. I have a Maven project using Spring and I call assembly-single and build a runnable jar. This project works fine from the IDE but when I run it as the runnable jar I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 8 in
 XML document from class path resource [properties.xml] is invalid; nested excep
tion is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 62; cvc-elt.
1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadB
eanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
[...]
```

My properties.xml file looks like the following. Notice I have schemaLocation correct and line 8 is http://www.springframework.org/schema/context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:test.properties"  system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

<!-- -->

</beans>
```

Comment: Which Spring version are you using?

Comment: I believe 3.2.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking around to other solutions I saw that some people suggested putting the classpath of the xsd directly into the beans tag. So I went ahead and tried this.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
classpath:/org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
</beans>
```

This solution seemed to work for the beans but not for context. My next solution I looked into an article I found a while ago stating that it might be related to Maven overwriting the spring.schemas file and not appending to the file ([this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8654175/823188)). I realized that my spring.schemas only included MVC schemas so I looked into the suggestion of using Maven Shade to build my jar [(using this as an example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160534/how-to-create-spring-based-executable-jar-with-maven). Shade will allow for a transformer that will tell maven to append to the file rather than overwrite allowing for multiple dependencies to use the same file.

Final pom:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.mainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                    <finalName>Filename</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are in an offline mode, I assume Spring validates your beans using schemas from its own jar. Thus you should use an aligned versions for the xml schemas as of the spring dependency version.

In your *properties.xml* descriptor I can see you are using the ***3.0*** schema version so you should be using the ***3.0.x*** dependency version, otherwise update your schema version to match the Spring version.

### Edit:

Since you are using the *3.2* version, update your xml bean descriptor to fit in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
<!-- -->
</beans>
```

Comment: Offline mode isn't the issue I validated I have the issue on my own machine as well. When I look at the spring-beans.jar package I see the .xsd for 3.0 format versus 3.0.x format. Do you mean to change the .xsd references?

Comment: I did end up using 3.2 on my own but there was more to the issue than this. I think 3.0 would have worked fine as well since the issue didn't seem to be with the schema location. See my answer I posted. It is my solution.