# How Spring finds the XSD file from classpath

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

In our spring configuration we put the beans tag like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Now spring has to find out from my calsspath for the location of the files  `spring-beans.xsd` & `spring-context.xsd`.

I have found some xsd files at this path:

> spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar/org/springframework/context/config

```
spring-context-2.5.xsd
spring-context-3.0.xsd
spring-context-3.1.xsd
spring-context-3.2.xsd
spring-context-4.0.xsd
spring-context-4.1.xsd
```

When searching for spring-beans.xsd file I found it some files in this path:

> spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml

```
spring-beans-2.5.xsd
spring-beans-3.0.xsd
spring-beans-3.1.xsd
spring-beans-3.2.xsd
spring-beans-4.0.xsd
spring-beans-4.1.xsd
```

How spring will know where to look for this file as there is no link between the schema location in my `beans` tag and the actual location of this file. Also I am able to find out files like this `spring-beans-<version>.xsd` then how spring will know what is `spring-beans.xsd` even when we do not specify any version in `<beans>` tag.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some spring libraries contain some file like [META-INF/spring.schemas](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-registration)

> The properties file called 'spring.schemas' contains a mapping of XML
> Schema locations (referred to along with the schema declaration in XML
> files that use the schema as part of the 'xsi:schemaLocation'
> attribute) to classpath resources. This file is needed to prevent
> Spring from absolutely having to use a default EntityResolver that
> requires Internet access to retrieve the schema file. If you specify
> the mapping in this properties file, Spring will search for the schema
> on the classpath

**e.g.**

*spring.schemas of spring-beans-x.x.x-RELEASE.jar*

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
```

In few words, above properties allows it to map XSD resource to [schemaLocation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#schemaLocation) attribute.

For more details, also see [Need understanding of spring.handlers and spring.schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609322/need-understanding-of-spring-handlers-and-spring-schemas) .

Comment: How it is work? 
Where is the code which indicate that mapping locates in spring.schemas