# Liquibase, local XSD reference

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, liquibase

I am using my liquibase xml config file (spring integration) with follow notation

```
<databaseChangeLog 
      xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog  
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
```

So.. I would use my app offline mode and i put "classpath" notation into my changelog:

```
<databaseChangeLog 
      xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog  
      classpath:xsd/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
```

But i  have follow error. Can you help me?

```
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:592)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:610)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:582)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2175)
```

Comment: I had found this working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609322/need-understanding-of-spring-handlers-and-spring-schemas

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by adding the related XSD file *dbchangelog-3.5.xsd* **locally** inside the project and updating the Liquibase configuration file (the `xsi:schemaLocation` part) like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">
```

So now the XSD file location is configured like `dbchangelog-3.5.xsd`. Just make sure the XSD file is located in the **same directory** as the Liquibase configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I have to search for the file in the classpath. Your solution is not the one requested