# Configuring Spring Batch with Maven

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Configuring Spring Batch with Maven. JDK used: 1.6, Spring Batch version 2.1.8.RELEASE; Spring version 3.0.5.RELEASE. Getting run time exception as below:

```
D:\SpringProject\SpringTry\target>java -jar SpringTry-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar jobs/helloWorld.xml helloWorldJob
2012-09-02 00:23:51,650 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] - <Refreshing org.springframework.context.
support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@b29c9d: startup date [Sun Sep 02 00:23:51 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy>
2012-09-02 00:23:51,769 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from class path
 resource [jobs/helloWorld.xml]>
2012-09-02 00:23:53,854 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from class path
 resource [launch-context.xml]>
2012-09-02 00:23:53,929 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner] - <Job Terminated in error: Configuration
 problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch]
Offending resource: class path resource [jobs/helloWorld.xml]
>
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler fo
r XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch]
Offending resource: class path resource [jobs/helloWorld.xml]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this. Also noticed that Spring 2.5.6 is getting downloaded everytime, along with version mentioned 3.0.5

My manifest looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0
Main-Class: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner
Class-Path: lib/spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar lib/xstream-1.3.jar lib/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar lib/jettison-1.1.jar lib/spring-aop-2.5.6.jar lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar lib/spring-tx-2.5.6.jar lib/spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar lib/maven-resources-plugin-2.4.3.jar lib/maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-project-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-profile-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-core-2.0.6.jar lib/wagon-file-1.0-beta-2.jar lib/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.0.6.jar lib/wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-2.jar lib/wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-2.jar lib/jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar lib/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar lib/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar lib/wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-2.jar lib/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.6.jar lib/commons-cli-1.0.jar lib/wagon-ssh-external-1.0-beta-2.jar lib/wagon-ssh-common-1.0-beta-2.jar lib/maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.6.jar lib/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar lib/wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-2.jar lib/jsch-0.1.27.jar lib/classworlds-1.1.jar lib/maven-artifact-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-settings-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-model-2.0.6.jar lib/maven-monitor-2.0.6.jar lib/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar lib/junit-3.8.1.jar lib/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar lib/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-4.jar lib/plexus-build-api-0.0.4.jar lib/plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved by adding maven-shade-plugin as detailed in the:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8574629/1419116

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are either:

- simply using a version of spring-batch-core jar (Maven dependency) which has version below 2.0. Schema naming works for version 2.0 and above. If it's the case, update your dependency

or

- You have the correct (higher than 2.0) version of spring-batch-core in your project's pom.xml, but you also have a transitive dependency which brings into your project an earlier version of spring-batch-core. If that's the case, try the following:

  > mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.springframework.batch

this will list all the dependencies that bring in their own version of spring-batch dependencies. Add an exclude entry on spring-batch-core for those dependencies, something like this:

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>whatever.group</groupId>
          <artifactId>whateverArtifact</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. The dependency tree shows: [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) SpringTry --- [INFO] com.my.batch:SpringTry:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO] +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile [INFO] | \- (org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate) [INFO] \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile. Since duplicate is omitted can I assume that this is not the reason for the issue