# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/task]?

Tags: java, xml, spring, akka

- I have a project that generates a `jar` let's call it `projectA.jar`. When this project runs, it is able to wire all its dependencies
- We are creating a new project (wrapper) which have maven dependency on `projectA.jar`
- As a first step, we are trying to call the same class as `projectA` was calling. When I do that I see error as

> 05 Jun 2015 18:32:44,430 [DEBUG]
>   [EnterpriseConnector-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate| No
>   XML 'id' specified - using 'RESTcloudRegistryLoader' as bean name and
>   [] as aliases 05 Jun 2015 18:32:44,430 [DEBUG]
>   [EnterpriseConnector-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate| No
>   XML 'id' specified - using 'remoteResourceManager' as bean name and []
>   as aliases 05 Jun 2015 18:32:44,449 [DEBUG]
>   [EnterpriseConnector-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver|
>   Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings:
>   {http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/c=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler,
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler}
>
> 05 Jun 2015 18:32:44,450 [INFO ]
>   [EnterpriseConnector-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]
>   com.shn.logs.common.OSUtils| Current Process ID 22924 Operating
>   System: Mac OS X 10.10.3 [ERROR] [06/05/2015 18:32:44.450]
>   [EnterpriseConnector-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]
>   [akka://EnterpriseConnector/user/logProcessorSupervisor/logprocessor]
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
>   XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/task]
>   Offending resource: class path resource [context.xml]
>
> ```
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:316)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at com.shn.logs.controller.LogReaderDisruptor.createAppContext(LogReaderDisruptor.java:148)
> ```

I looked what `Loaded Schema mapping` is loading and realized that infact  `http://www.springframework.org/schema/task` is not loaded.

However, in my `context.xml`, I see it

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans org/springframework/schema/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context org/springframework/schema/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc org/springframework/schema/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task org/springframework/schema/spring-task-3.2.xsd
        /springframework/schema/spring-cache.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="false" default-autowire="no"
       default-dependency-check="none">
```

Also, I tried looking into the jar if `spring-task` is loaded and I see it in there

```
jar -tvf main-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep spring-task
 12199 Mon Jun 01 13:41:22 PDT 2015 org/springframework/schema/spring-task-3.2.xsd
 10764 Fri Feb 20 02:46:26 PST 2015 org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd
 12825 Fri Feb 20 02:46:26 PST 2015 org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.1.xsd
   541 Fri Feb 20 02:46:26 PST 2015 org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task.gif
 11991 Fri Feb 20 02:46:26 PST 2015 org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd
 12286 Fri Feb 20 02:46:26 PST 2015 org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.0.xsd
 12286 Fri Feb 20 02:46:26 PST 2015 org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd
```

I thought it could be `maven-shade-plugin` issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11978331/379235), but my plugin already includes them

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                                    <finalName>original-${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                                    <!-- <shadedClassifierName></shadedClassifierName> -->
                                    <filters>
                                        <filter>
                                            <artifact>org.apache.tomcat.embed:*</artifact>
                                            <excludes>
                                                <exclude>**/JSSESocketFactory*</exclude>
                                                <exclude>**/AbstractEndpoint*</exclude>
                                            </excludes>
                                        </filter>
                                        <filter>
                                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                            <excludes>
                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                                <exclude>log4j.xml</exclude>
                                            </excludes>
                                        </filter>
                                    </filters>
                                    <transformers>

                                                                                        <transformer
                                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                        <transformer
                                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                        </transformer>
                                        <transformer
                                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                        </transformer>
                                        <transformer
                                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                            <mainClass>com.shn.logs.controller.MainClass
                                            </mainClass>
                                        </transformer>
                                    </transformers>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

What is that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

replace **org/springframework/schema/spring-task-3.2.xsd** with **http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd**